# how to send json array in android retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I can't send json array to server. When I test in postman raw, it is ok, success return.

Postman Raw;

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 2,
        "name": "Umbrella",
        "price": 200,
        "quantity": 1,
        "totalprice": 200,
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "name": "Apple",
        "price": 200,
        "quantity": 1,
        "totalprice": 200,
        "user_id": 1
    }
]
```

APIInterface;

```
@POST("example/api/order")
Call<JSONArray> postOrder(@Body JSONArray jsonArray);
```

CartActivity;

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Cart cart : cartList) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("product_id", cart.getProduct_id());
        jsonObject.put("name", cart.getName());
        jsonObject.put("price", cart.getPrice());
        jsonObject.put("quantity", cart.getQuantity());
        jsonObject.put("totalprice", cart.getTotalprice());
        jsonObject.put("user_id", cart.getUser_id());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    }
    Log.e("JSONArray", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
} catch (JSONException jse) {
    jse.printStackTrace();
}
```

Log;

```
E/JSONArray: [{"product_id":1,"name":"Umbrella","price":200,"quantity":1,"totalprice":200,"user_id":1},{"product_id":2,"name":"Apple","price":89,"quantity":1,"totalprice":89,"user_id":1}]
```

Error Message from server;

```
{"values":[{"nameValuePairs":{"product_id":1,"name":"Umbrella","price":200,"quantity":1,"totalprice":200,"user_id":1}},{"nameValuePairs":{"product_id":2,"name":"Apple","price":89,"quantity":1,"totalprice":89,"user_id":1}}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Post JSON array using Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820740/how-to-post-json-array-using-retrofit-2)

Comment: The best way is create Model class and pass it as body

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can directly send the array of objects as parameter. Retrofit will handle the conversion. Change your interface method like this:

```
@POST("example/api/order")
Call<JSONArray> postOrder(@Body List<Cart> cartList);
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435868/5453659), you will get an idea.

Comment: How to do same in kotlin

Comment: `@POST("example/api/order")
fun postOrder(@Body cartlist: List<Cart>): Call<JSONArray>
`

Answer (score 0):

send like this:-

```
@POST("example/api/order")
Call<JSONArray> postOrder(@Query ("data") JSONArray jsonArray);
```

Comment: What is `@Query ("data")` for **values**, **nameValuePairs**?

Comment: ask your backend team to send jsonArray in "data".

Comment: to change with key ?

Comment: `@Body` annotation will work too. No need to change to query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload array of object using Retrofit then follow the steps. It will work 100%.
In my case I have 2 params one is userid and second is location_data. In second params I have to pass array of objects.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/send_array_data")
Call<StartResponseModal> postData(@Field("user_id") String user_id,
                                             @Field("location_data") String 
jsonObject);
```

then in your MainActivity.class.

```
 ArrayList<JSONObject> obj_arr;
 try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                obj_arr = new ArrayList<>();
                 // LocationData is model class. 
                for (LocationData cart : arrayList) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("latitude", cart.getLatitude());
                    jsonObject.put("longitude", cart.getLongitude());
                    jsonObject.put("address", cart.getAddress());
                    jsonObject.put("battery", cart.getBattery());
                    jsonObject.put("is_gps_on", cart.getIs_gps_on());
                    jsonObject.put("is_internet_on", cart.getIs_internet_on());
                    jsonObject.put("type", cart.getType());
                    jsonObject.put("date_time", cart.getDate_time());
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                    obj_arr.add(jsonObject);
                }
                Log.e("JSONArray", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
            } catch (JSONException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }




 String user_id = SharedPreferenceUtils.getString(getActivity(), 
 Const.USER_ID);
    RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = 
 APIClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
    Call<StartResponseModal> call = 
 retrofitAPI.postData(user_id,obj_arr.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StartResponseModal>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StartResponseModal> call, 
  Response<StartResponseModal> response) {
            // Handle success
            if (response.isSuccessful() && 
  response.body().getErrorCode().equals("0")) {
                // Process the response here
                Log.e("Hello Room data send","Success");
                deleteItemsFromDatabase();


            } else {
                // Handle API error
                Log.e("Hello Room data send","failed else");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StartResponseModal> call, Throwable t) {
            // Handle failure
            Log.e("Hello Room send","failure");

        }
    });
```