# Posting raw json array using postman without POJO

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit2

I am trying to post a raw json array using retrofit but it adds an additional tag in front of the array in the body. The data I want to post is as below:

```
[    
    {
        "id": "b354dd-ea44-8c3s6",
        "values":"1",
        "checksum": "A02",
    }, 
    {
        "id": "t527sh-ea44-8c3s6",
        "values":"0",
        "checksum": "A32",
    }
]
```

The problem that I am facing is, retrofit adds and extra tag "values" in front of this array:

```
{"values": [    
        {
            "id": "b354dd-ea44-8c3s6",
            "values":"1",
            "checksum": "A02",
        }, 
        {
            "id": "t527sh-ea44-8c3s6",
            "values":"0",
            "checksum": "A32",
        }
    ]
}
```

Because of the extra "values" tag, the server is not accepting the data. Is there any way to prevent retrofit from putting in the tag? The array that I am passing to the retrofit request is `JSONArray`.
I cannot create a POJO because I would have to send the data as it is, without any manipulation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this, I think is that you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982069/7198727

Comment: This does not help me as I cannot have a POJO class. The son data that I receive needs to be uploaded to the API as is.