# POST a JSONArray using retrofit android studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit

Currently I am individually sending variables via POST. I would like to compile all items to a JSON array and send it to my server.

```java
public interface ProfilesApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("upload_profiles.php")
    Call<ResponsePojo> uploadProfiles(
            @Field("profResCodePost") String resCode,
            @Field("profProfilePost") String profile,
            @Field("profNameRespondentPost") String nameRespondent,
            @Field("profDateSurveyed") String dateSurveyed
    );
}
```

is a JSON array also "@Field" or should it be "@Body"?

```java
 JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < listProfiles.size(); i++) {

                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

                ListProfiles currentProfile = listProfiles.get(i);

                jsonObject.addProperty("profResCodePost", currentProfile.profileResCode);
                jsonObject.addProperty("profProfilePost", currentProfile.profileProfile);;
                jsonObject.addProperty("profOwnerTypePost", currentProfile.profileOwnerType);
                jsonObject.addProperty("profNameRespondentPost", currentProfile.profileNameRespondent);
                jsonObject.addProperty("profDateSurveyed", currentProfile.dateSurveyed);
                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            }
```

What I had in mind was kind of like this.

```java
public interface ProfilesApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("upload_profiles.php")
    Call<ResponsePojo> uploadProfiles(
            @Body("jsonArrayProfile")  JsonArray jsonArray
    );
}
```

The error when I try to use the @Body is "cannot find symbol methd value()"

when I try this

```java
public interface ProfilesJsonArray {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("upload_profiles.php")
    Call<ResponsePojo> uploadProfiles(
            @Body(JsonArray jsonArray)
    );
}
```

The error is "error: ')' expected"

**EDIT 1**: *I added a Java class for JSONProfiles like this*

```
public class JSONProfiles {

    @SerializedName("profResCodePost")
    private final String resCode;
    @SerializedName("profProfilePost")
    private final String profile;
    @SerializedName("profNameRespondentPost")
    private final String name_respondent;
    @SerializedName("profDateSurveyed")
    private final String date_of_survey;
}
```

Then did this to the POST method

```
public interface ProfilesJsonArray {

    @Headers({
            "Content-type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("upload_profiles.php")
     Call<ResponsePojo> uploadProfiles(
            @Body(ArrayList <JSONProfiles> jsonprof);
    )
}
```

Still not working with error "error: illegal start of type"

[Image of code for Profile Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQn1e.png)

[**Image with semicolon same error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcYlA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List<YourModel>` instead, retrofit will do the conversion for you. Check these answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982069/4491971

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34435868/4491971

Comment: thank you for the comment. I tried making a Java class for the items I would like to send but I still encounter a syntax error. Also I tried using a list it still won't work.

@mohit-ajwani

Comment: You are missing semicolon after `Body` closing bracket. It should be `@Body(JsonArray jsonArray);` this is just an example. Add the semicolon and it should resolve the error of `error: illegal start of type`. This resolves the image error.

Comment: I tried using the one in the first link like this. with or without a semicolon it doesnt work. I think there is a problem with the JSONProfiles class. I added an image with a semicolon.
`@POST("example/api/order")
Call<JSONArray> postOrder(@Body List<Cart> cartList);`